# Django: KeyError in admin on listing boolean fields

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Whenever I decided to list a Boolean Field in my list_display such as 'active' (see example)

```
class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['name', 'created']
    list_display = ['name', 'active', 'created']
```

I get the following error...

```
KeyError at /admin/web/company/

'\x01'
```

This happens on any Boolean values I try to list. I'm using grappelli as the admin skin. I have included the full error below and my model.

**Model:**

```
class Company(models.Model):
    companyid = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True, db_column='companyID')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=105)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    modified = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'company'
```

**Error:**
        Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/web/company/

Django Version: 1.4.2
Python Version: 2.7.2
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.flatpages',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'grappelli.dashboard',
 'grappelli',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'web')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /Users/user/Documents/workspace/Ares/grappelli/templates/admin/change_list.html, error at line 222

   212 :                     {% blocktrans count cl.formset.errors|length as counter %}Please correct the error below.{% plural %}Please correct the errors below.{% endblocktrans %}


   213 :                 </p>


   214 :                 {{ cl.formset.non_form_errors }}


   215 :             {% endif %}


   216 :             <!-- MANAGEMENT FORM -->


   217 :             {% if cl.formset %}


   218 :                 {{ cl.formset.management_form }}


   219 :             {% endif %}


   220 :             <!-- CHANGELIST-RESULTS -->


   221 :             {% block result_list %}


   222 :                  {% result_list cl %} 


   223 :             {% endblock %}


   224 :         </section>


   225 :         <!-- PAGINATION BOTTOM -->


   226 :         {% if not cl.result_count == 0 %}


   227 :             {% block pagination_bottom %}


   228 :                 <div class="grp-module">


   229 :                     <div class="grp-row">{% pagination cl %}</div>


   230 :                 </div>


   231 :             {% endblock %}


   232 :         {% endif %}


Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  136.                     response = response.render()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  104.             self._set_content(self.rendered_content)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  81.         content = template.render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  123.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  123.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  62.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  62.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  1178.                     _dict = func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py" in result_list
  278.             'results': list(results(cl))}
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py" in results
  256.             yield ResultList(None, items_for_result(cl, res, None))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py" in __init__
  248.         super(ResultList, self).__init__(*items)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py" in items_for_result
  204.                     result_repr = display_for_field(value, f)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/util.py" in display_for_field
  321.         return _boolean_icon(value)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py" in _boolean_icon
  164.                       {True: 'yes', False: 'no', None: 'unknown'}[field_val])

Exception Type: KeyError at /admin/web/company/
Exception Value: '\x01'
```

Comment: I think the issue is you are specifying the `fields = ['name', 'created']` to show but in `list_display` you are adding one more field `active` which is not included in `fields`, change your `fields` to `fields = ['name', 'created', 'active']` and see what happen. (Not sure about it)

Comment: Are you accessing an existing MySQL db that you reverse engineered?

Comment: @dgel yes that's exactly what I'm doing, the model was generated, why?

Comment: @Aamir Adnan sorry thats not the issue i dont think anyhow, tried adding in active with no joy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue using some Django models on an existing MySQL database that had models from Hibernate. It used BIT(1) as the boolean type. As long as your 1 and 0 values appear as `\x01` and `\x00` in Python you should be able to salvage the below `BooleanField`

Here's some leads:

```
class MyBooleanField(models.BooleanField):

    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def get_internal_type(self):
        return "MyBooleanField"

    def db_type(self):
        return 'bit(1)'

    def to_python(self, value):
        if value in (True, False): return value
        if value in ('t', 'True', '1', '\x01'): return True  
        if value in ('f', 'False', '0', '\x00'): return False

    def get_db_prep_value(self, value):  
        return 0x01 if value else 0x00
```

from: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1869/

Then in your models :

```
class Company(models.Model):
    active = models.MyBooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just posting an update (on the correct answer by bakkal) for django ≥ 3.0, as **Subfieldbase()** has been deprecated and replaced by **from_db_value()**. [Read the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-model-fields/#converting-values-to-python-objects).

```
    class MyBooleanField(models.BooleanField):

        def get_internal_type(self):
            return "MyBooleanField"

        def db_type(self):
            return 'bit(1)'

        def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
            if value in ('t', 'True', '1', b'\x01'): return True
            elif value in ('f', 'False', '0', b'\x00'): return False
            else: return None

        def to_python(self, value):
            if value in (True, False): return value
            if value in ('t', 'True', '1', b'\x01'): return True
            if value in ('f', 'False', '0', b'\x00'): return False

        def get_db_prep_value(self, value):
            return 0x01 if value else 0x00
```